# How can i emulate a ps/2 keyboard with raspberry pi3

Tags: rpi.gpio, keyboard, emulation, python-3

So I am working on an medical machine which runs on microcontroller(So,No OS).It gets the input from ps/2 keyboard. I would like to automate it. I would like some basic idea and some help on how to do it. I tried connecting the gpio pins directly to the ps/2 port and have damaged the pi. So any precautions on how to proceed would be great.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: I have read the details of the protocol from this site http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2protocol/ and tried replicating it using the ps2dev arduino module for emulating keyboard on arduino